# How to relabel ellipsis button for modal UITypeEditor in PropertyGrid?

Tags: .net, winforms, propertygrid, uitypeeditor

I have a Windows forms PropertyGrid and a customer UITypeEditor per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditoreditstyle.aspx

> Displays an ellipsis (...) button to start a modal dialog box, which requires user input before continuing a program, or a modeless dialog box, which stays on the screen and is available for use at any time but permits other user activities.

That ellipsis button is pretty small. How can I relabel it with a more helpful label?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short, you can't. The basic MS PropertyGrid does not allow you to customize this text. It even uses a bitmap with 3 dots instead of text anyway and the width of the control is fixed.

*Disclaimer: I'm the developer behind [Smart PropertyGrid.Net](http://www.visualhint.com/propertygrid), which can do what you want to achieve.*

Comment: Is this still true?

Comment: @HassanVoyeau Not sure what you mean by "still true" but afaik 1. MSPG was not updated with new features and 2. yes SPG.Net allows to customize the button.

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657453/how-to-change-the-text-on-the-button-of-uitypeeditor

Comment: @HassanVoyeau Well, you crosslink the 2 questions but it won't change anything. MSPG can't do it.