# How to change the '...' text on the button of UITypeEditor?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-experience, propertygrid

I have a PropertyGrid with many properties, like this:

[image: PropertyGrid]

I want to let users tweak these, but in addition, I want to give them a button that says "Guess", that will attempt to choose the "best" value for the property. I found that `UITypeEditor` gives almost what I want.

I have the following code

```
public class GuessMyValueTypeEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        return ((MyClass)context.Instance).GuessMyValue();
    }
}
[System.ComponentModel.Category("Adjustable")]
[EditorAttribute(typeof(GuessMyValueTypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public int MyValue
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

When the user tries to change `MyValue`, he gets a button which says <kbd>...</kbd>. When pressed, it invokes my code `GuessMyValue`, and sets the property to a new value.

[image: PropertyGrid]

This is all good, but I find the "..." prompt very unintuitive. Users expect a dialog when pressing a button which says "...", and my code resets the property without any user interaction, so this feature looks like a bug.

How can I change the prompt on the button to something like <kbd>Guess</kbd>?

If it's not possible, how can I customize a `UITypeEditor` to show a button of my choice, instead of its standard "edit" button?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to access/modify the button.  Perhaps this is something better handled by a [DesignerVerb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.designerverb?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) that would show in the propertygrid as a command for the component? See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49612004/2592875) for an example of the idea.

Comment: It's not possible officially. What you can do with a hack is change the bitmap (the 3 dots are a bitmap, not a text), or set a text but you cannot change the size of the button... well at least I wasn't able to do it with my tests. So you won't be able to display "Guess". Maybe a small "G"...

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603269/how-to-relabel-ellipsis-button-for-modal-uitypeeditor-in-propertygrid/13145574